# Question regarding FtpInboundFileSynchronizer running with multiple instances/applications

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

I've recently been trying to configure and set up a spring boot application that will later be run in kubernetes and have multiple pods running of it. The application is meant to download files from a FTP server. I've found some existing code for doing this in Springboot, particularly `FtpInboundFileSynchronizer` and so I tried set it up and make sure it works. I have a working solution with a `ConcurrentMetaDataStore`. So my only real question is if it will be fine running it with multiple instances or if I require something additional for it to be run with multiple pods?

My configuration looks something like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ftp")
public class FtpConfiguration
{
private final static int PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE = 2;
private final static int DEFAULT_FTP_PORT = 21;
String host;
String username;
String password;
String localDirectory;
String remoteDirectory;
FtpRemoteFileTemplate template;
FtpInboundFileSynchronizer synchronizer;
DataSource templateSource;

@Bean
public ConcurrentMetadataStore metadataStore(DataSource dataSource)
{
    var jbdcMetaDatastore = new JdbcMetadataStore(dataSource);
    jbdcMetaDatastore.setTablePrefix("INT_");
    jbdcMetaDatastore.setRegion("TEMPORARY");
    jbdcMetaDatastore.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jbdcMetaDatastore;
}

@Bean
public DefaultFtpSessionFactory defaultFtpSessionFactory()
{
    DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    sf.setHost(host);
    sf.setUsername(username);
    sf.setPassword(password);
    sf.setPort(DEFAULT_FTP_PORT);
    sf.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    sf.setClientMode(PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE);
    return sf;
}

@Bean
FtpRemoteFileTemplate ftpRemoteFileTemplate(DefaultFtpSessionFactory dsf)
{
    return new FtpRemoteFileTemplate(dsf);
}

@Bean
FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer(DefaultFtpSessionFactory dsf)
{
    FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInSync = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(dsf);
    ftpInSync.setRemoteDirectory(remoteDirectory);
    ftpInSync.setFilter(ftpFileListFilter());
    return ftpInSync;
}

public FileListFilter<FTPFile> ftpFileListFilter()
{
    try (ChainFileListFilter<FTPFile> chain = new ChainFileListFilter<>())
    {
        chain.addFilter(new FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore(templateSource), "TEST"));
        return chain;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter", e);
    }
}
```

}

and then I just call the the `SynchronizeToLocalDirectory` method.

```
        FtpClient(
        FtpRemoteFileTemplate template, FtpInboundFileSynchronizer synchronizer,
        @Value("${ftp.remote-directory}") String remoteDirectory,
        @Value("${ftp.local-directory}") String localDirectory)
{
    this.template = template;
    this.synchronizer = synchronizer;
    this.remoteDirectory = remoteDirectory;
    this.localDirectory = localDirectory;
}


        synchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(remoteDirectory);
        synchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(new File(localDirectory));
```

Would this solution handle multiple applications without problems? Or what else would I need? Does the `ConcurrentMetaData` store alone make sure this works? (so for example there wouldn't be a conflict/crash if two instances at the same time try to synchronise same directory as they'd both be fine thanks to the metastore being `@Transactional`).

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct: as long as all your pods are connecting to the same data base, that `JdbcMetadataStore` will ensure that no concurrent read for the same file are going to happen.

It is not clear, though, why would one use an `FtpInboundFileSynchronizer` manually, but not via an `FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` and subsequent integration flow, but that's I guess fully different story and question.

On the other hand: why do you ask this question at all? Didn't you try your solution? Isn't docs enough to be sure where and how to go: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/file.html#remote-persistent-flf ?

Comment: Thanks Artem! I was trying to create a small solution as possible so I was trying to scale away as much as possible and I simply just started with piece of code / functionality at the time. Started with FtpRemoteFileTemplate, then added a filter onto..then the store and so on.   I've during the day found examples (some I believe were yours) that had examples where this FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource was being used. Perhaps it would improve the solution and I'd probably add that into the next step, but I don't competly get the whole reasoning behind using messages everywhere.

Comment: And as to why I posted this question was because a colleague took my entire solution, stripped away everything but the FtpRemoteFileTemplate. Then built a locking mechanism ontop of it for downloading files and so on. He is a more experienced developer than me, so when I asked why and he said there'd be problems with downloading lots of files and especially large files. Made me insecure & rethink the logic. From everything I could see in docs, it seemed like my solution would be fine with those cases (I also found that there's a fetchMaxSize and like mentioned @Transactional part of code).

Comment: And also to respond to your question regarding the documentation, no it is a bit bulky and can be a bit confusing. Sometimes it seems like there's a lot of extra abstraction on top of basic things. It can make it a bit unclear. Perhaps I am just easily lost but I feel like the fact that you link a part of documentation that's not as clear (to me at least) as another part of the docs, makes my point. Since I think this is where I figured out to use a ConcurrentMetaDataStore -> https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-inbound

Comment: Right, if you store those files locally, it indeed may lead to some problems, that's why we have an `FtpStreamingMessageSource` to avoid local file system overhead https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-streaming. Right, the docs I linked is really a part of broader channel adapter concept. It feels like you just abuse some components from Spring Integration where you are not going to use messaging in your project at all.

Comment: The worry was not with local directory, but more that there would be a clash when writing it. But yes as I mentioned, perhaps FtpStreamingMessageSource on top of it would be an improvement. I was merely curious if I understood things correctly. I have already approved his own solution now where we will instead take care of everything ourselves (locking, renaming files, check list of files etc). Yeah, I only really was looking for a FTPDownloader (and later on added the requirement of concurrency).